# Не запускается iOS-приложение через Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios

Доброго времени суток. У меня такой вопрос: у меня есть аккаунт разработчика, в котором зарегистрирован мой iPad. Но после обновления до 8.2 я не могу выбрать свой iPad в списке устройств для запуска, возле него написано Ineligible device. Как это исправить? Спасибо.

Comment: Может, провод перетерся, может, itunse тупит, либо xCode. Попробуйте ребут всего мака.

Comment: Это может быть из-за провода? Просто, у него порвалась изоляция, это может быть причиной?

Comment: Да у меня вообще провод работает на одной стороне и я полчал подобую ошибку если не верно провод воткну.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо обновить XCode. Он не определяет устройства с версией операционной системы старше, чем версия его SDK.

Comment: У меня Xcode 6.3 beta 3

Comment: Вчера эта проблема решилась обновлением xcode до 6.2

Comment: Еще такой вопрос, у Вас сейчас работает iTunes Connect? У меня открывается окно входа, а после входа появляется белый экран.

Comment: У меня работает. На этом экране у них новый интерфейс грузится. Он весьма тяжел - попробуйте немного подождать.

Comment: Аа, понятно

Comment: Ну не знаю, пять минут уже жду и ничего не грузится.

Comment: Попробуй в другом браузере. Интерфейс новый, необкатаный. Если не получится - пиши им в саппорт.